# Save an object using Celery and Gino

Tags: python, orm, celery, fastapi, gino

I have the following pipeline

Event model (based on Gino 'db' object):

```
class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "events"

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger(), primary_key=True)
    request_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False)
    service = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    status_code = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    response_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False)
```

FastApi app has a POST view with call to celery task to pass the data of the Event object:

```
@router.post("/events/add")
async def add_event(event: EventModel):
    event_data = {'request_timestamp': event.request_timestamp.replace(tzinfo=None),
                  'service': event.service,
                  'url': event.url,
                  'status_code': event.status_code,
                  'response_time': event.response_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
                  }

    task = celery_app.send_task("monitoring_service.src.monitoring_service.worker.celery_worker.add_to_db",
                                kwargs=event_data)

    return JSONResponse(content="Event recorded successfully", status_code=200)
```

And celery worker which must save an Event object to database:

```
@celery_app.task(acks_late=True)
async def add_to_db(request_timestamp, service, url, status_code, response_time):
    event = await Event.create(
        request_timestamp=datetime.strptime(request_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'),
        service=service,
        url=url,
        status_code=status_code,
        response_time=datetime.strptime(response_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'),
    )

    return {"status": True}
```

Now I'm receiving an error during object saving process:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 479, in trace_task

mark_as_done(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 158, in mark_as_done

self.store_result(task_id, result, state, request=request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 442, in store_result

self._store_result(task_id, result, state, traceback,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 51, in _inner

return fun(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 130, in _store_result

session.commit()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1042, in commit

self.transaction.commit()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit

self._prepare_impl()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl

self.session.flush()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2523, in flush

self._flush(objects)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2664, in _flush

transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__

compat.raise_(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_

raise exception

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2624, in _flush

flush_context.execute()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute

rec.execute(self)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 586, in execute

persistence.save_obj(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 230, in save_obj

_emit_update_statements(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 994, in _emit_update_statements

c = cached_connections[connection].execute(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1014, in execute

return meth(self, multiparams, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection

return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1127, in _execute_clauseelement

ret = self._execute_context(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1207, in _execute_context

self._handle_dbapi_exception(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception

util.raise_(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_

raise exception

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1205, in _execute_context

context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 858, in _init_compiled

param = dict(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 861, in <genexpr>

processors[key](compiled_params[key])

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1689, in process

value = dumps(value, protocol)

sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError: (builtins.TypeError) cannot pickle 'coroutine' object


warn(RuntimeWarning(

[2021-02-19 10:19:39,010: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task monitoring_service.src.monitoring_service.worker.celery_worker.add_to_db[994ae754-f216-4fa9-b502-5fbb0221011c] raised unexpected: SQLAlchemyError("(builtins.TypeError) cannot pickle 'coroutine' object")

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 479, in trace_task

mark_as_done(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 158, in mark_as_done

self.store_result(task_id, result, state, request=request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 442, in store_result

self._store_result(task_id, result, state, traceback,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 51, in _inner

return fun(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 130, in _store_result

session.commit()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1042, in commit

self.transaction.commit()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit

self._prepare_impl()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl

self.session.flush()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2523, in flush

self._flush(objects)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2664, in _flush

transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__

compat.raise_(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_

raise exception

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2624, in _flush

flush_context.execute()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute

rec.execute(self)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 586, in execute

persistence.save_obj(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 230, in save_obj

_emit_update_statements(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 994, in _emit_update_statements

c = cached_connections[connection].execute(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1014, in execute

return meth(self, multiparams, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection

return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1127, in _execute_clauseelement

ret = self._execute_context(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1207, in _execute_context

self._handle_dbapi_exception(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception

util.raise_(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_

raise exception

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1205, in _execute_context

context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 858, in _init_compiled

param = dict(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 861, in <genexpr>

processors[key](compiled_params[key])

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1689, in process

value = dumps(value, protocol)

sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError: (builtins.TypeError) cannot pickle 'coroutine' object
```

If I call `event = await Event.create(...)` inside a view it is successfull and saves data to db.
If I delete 'async/await' from Celery worker, this error doesn't show up, Celery task has 'SUCCESS' state  but database is empty.
Can't really understand what is not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: currently, Celery is not able to handle asynchronous functions as tasks. You need to wrap it with `asyncio.run` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run):

```py
async def add_to_db(request_timestamp, service, url, status_code, response_time):
    event = await Event.create(
        request_timestamp=datetime.strptime(request_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'),
        service=service,
        url=url,
        status_code=status_code,
        response_time=datetime.strptime(response_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'),
    )

@celery_app.task(acks_late=True)
def add_to_db_task(request_timestamp, service, url, status_code, response_time):
    asyncio.run(add_to_db(request_timestamp, service, url, status_code, response_time))
    return {"status": True}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @frankie567 this helped me. In addition I had to use Gino engine context manager in async function because my celery worker lives in another module and service. So it works fine now:


`async def add_to_db(request_timestamp, service, url, status_code, response_time):

    async with db.with_bind(DB_DSN) as engine:
        event = await Event.create(...)
`